# Distinct for two columns using SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select query as shown below:

```
 select cola,colb,colc,cold,cole,colf,colg,colh,coli,colj,colk
 from test
 where cola in (select colb from test);
```

How can I get only distinct `cola` and `colb` from different columns?

My try:

```
 select Distinct cola,colb,colc,cold,cole,colf,colg,colh,coli,colj,colk
 from test
 where cola in (select distinct colb from test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
 select cola,colb,colc,cold,cole,colf,colg,colh,coli,colj,colk,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cola, colb ORDER BY cola)
 from test
 where cola in (select colb from test)
)
SELECT  cola,colb,colc,cold,cole,colf,colg,colh,coli,colj,colk
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

This selects arbitrary rows for every cola, colb combination. If you want to fine-tune it change `ORDER BY cola` to something more meaningful.